# Axis2 how to restrict one web service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have two web services.
One that I use for the mobile applications to select/update data to/from the database. I was asked to write another web service for third parties to collect public data from our database.  I don't want my first service to be public.
If I give the link to my web service to anyone, they can see my other web services as well
For example,

http://server.mydomain.com/axis2/services/WebService?wsdl

Any one can list all my services using

http://server.mydomain.com/axis2/services/listService

Is there a way that I can hide one of my services from the public?

Any Idea????

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base URL is same, so, yes users can see all services. But this doesn't mean that they can access it as well. You can restrict access by putting some authentication/authorization.

But if you don't want people to even know about it. I will suggest better put it in a separate Axis engine. So that your URLs become different.

Comment: This a good idea! I really don't want people to know about the other service because only I am using it for mobile apps so I did not put any authentication check (Which is very bad). but now I can put the new service in another Axis2 engine as I don't mind changing the URL. Thanks